# jquery cycle link from external page to specific slide?

Tags: jquery, external, anchor, cycle

Been perusing all the other questions, and I can't figure this out. I have a home page that features certain slides from another page I have using the jquery cycle plugin. What I need to do is have the link on the home page link directly to a slide that isn't the first slide of a group. Nothing that complicated. I have a link like this on my home page:

```
<a href='portfolio.php'>SEE MORE</a>
```

I've looked into adding named anchors using the pagerAnchorBuilder and then referencing that anchor in my link. Successfully adds named anchors:

```
   pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    return '<li'+s+'><a href="#" name="portfolio'+(idx+1)+'">'+(idx+1)+'</a></li>';
    }
```

But linking to them does nothing. Ex:

```
<a href='portfolio.php#portfolio3>SEE MORE</a>
```

I'm thinking this is related to updateActivePagerLink. Is there a way to somehow have the named anchor tell the page with cycle which slide to make active? Or is there another approach that is easier? Seems like this would be a common application! I'm a beginner at jQuery. Can't figure it out!

Comment: OK, I'm close. I'm just passing a value to the page via URL parameter. I'm thinking now that I have the variable in JavaScript, can I just use te updateActivePagerLink to set the currSlideindex to that value, and hence the page will go to that index? Can't get the syntax right though. I have a numerical value (say "2"), and i just need to assign the currSlideIndex to that value right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adapting the [poor man's pager](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto2.html) jQuery Cycle example. In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meloncholy/ArzYn/), I've taken that code and changed it to use links rather than buttons.

It checks on page load for an anchor ID and, if it finds one, send a click event to the relevant element.

```
    if (location.hash)
    {
        $('#' + location.hash.substring(1)).click();
    }
```