# Link to a specific image/slide in gallerific

Tags: image, hyperlink, slide

I'm having problems with something which seems like an easy task, and most probably a stupid question. It will probably be my all time low experience in programming but I would really appreciate any help!

I'm using Galleriffic to display my portfolio site, and I am looking for a way to directly link to an image+description not being the first in the gallery. I would like it to link from other webpages, or from plain text/pdf documents.

In short, I would like it to link to a webaddress of slide 5 with something like:

```
<a href="MyFirstSlideshow.html#5">Slide 5</a>
```

but doing it this way obviously doesn't work.

Although others have tried to explain:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7910501/1074297

[jquery cycle link from external page to specific slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5463649/1074297)

I can not seem to accomplish it, and it does not help at all that I am not a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is too late, have been search the solutions for whole day, final found out the example 4 in the official website actually make the #link show on the address....so you can actually link the specific image ('slide'') from external page...amazing!!!!!

check this out
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-4.html#5

You can find the script after all the  or just before ... and place it to your template...it works well for me, hope it helps, good luck

Comment: sorry i mean after all the div just before /body